# Divs not wrapping horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 5 `divs` that I would like to align using 3 rows and  columns like so:

|    O   O    |
|    O   O    |
|    O          |

I'm new to flexbox, I don't seem to be able to wrap my divs. They appear to be centered within my parent div container in the following order:
  |     O     |
  |     O     |
  |     O     |
  |     O     |
  |     O     |

I want the `innerContainer` to wrap to the next line after two divs have been placed.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.containerBody {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.innerContainer {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 30%;
  height: 185px;
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- text -->
  <div class="containerBody">
    <!-- text -->
    <a>
      <div class="innerContainer">
        O
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="innerContainer">
        O
      </div>
    </a>
<a>
      <div class="innerContainer">
        O
      </div>
    </a>
<a>
      <div class="innerContainer">
        O
      </div>
    </a>
<a>
      <div class="innerContainer">
        O
      </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with `flexbox` is that the items you want to control with it need to be direct children of your flex container. Like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems I did not put in my HTML correctly here, I have edited it now. So I'm guessing I have to make the `<a>` the parent flex container. I will try it out.

Comment: I swapped `div.innerContainer` for `<a>` and it worker. Thanks!